# How to create your own controls in Android Studio

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-gridlayout

I looked at the official tutorial but I just don't get it.

This is my class:

```
public class mycontrol extends GridLayout {

public mycontrol(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}}
```

This is my res/layout/mycontrol.xml:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="60dp"
android:columnCount="4"
android:rowCount="2"
android:background="@drawable/cellshapeownstatus"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:id="@+id/my_status_id">

<TextView
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="doing stuff"
    android:id="@+id/myOwnName" /></GridLayout>
```

This is my res/layout/activity_main.xml, where I want to show mycontrol:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
android:paddingRight="2dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#0A3E61"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_id">


<com.example.test.mycontrol
    android:id="@+id/my_status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"/></LinearLayout>
```

Nothing shows up in the Designer Preview. I can build without errors, but it instantly crashes when I try to run it on my Phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to extend GridLayout and you forgot to inflate your xml:

```
public class MyControl extends FrameLayout {

  public MyControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      inflate(context, R.layout.mycontrol, this);
  }
}
```

layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
android:paddingRight="2dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#0A3E61"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_id">


<com.example.test.MyControl
    android:id="@+id/my_status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! :)

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class....

Answer (score 1):

Simply use 'include'

```
<include
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
layout="@layout/mycontrol"
/>
```